# Creating RPM from directory of files

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I just want a simple way to create an RPM from a directory full of files. I can't seem to find any simple way of doing this online?

I know that tools such as fpm exist for doing this, but I'd like to understand the RPM build process a little so would rather not use that.

The closest I've found is:

https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/building-simple-rpms-arbitary-files/

but I will be installing 100's of files - I don't really want to write an install command for each of them.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Jordan Sissel's FPM:

https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

It's magic for turning one thing in to the other, package to compressed directory and back.

Answer (score 2):

The rpmerizor (http://rpmerizor.sourceforge.net/) may be of interest.  The web page also lists other tools (including fpm) that do this kind of thing.